# Reason for Downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-answer

I have an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3477238/633100. It just got an unexpected downvote but no one ever left a comment on why the downvote was casted, a comment was there but was very vaguely stated. I see that lot of queries like these arise at Meta and wish to know why I got downvotes.

How can this answer be improved. Is it okay to leave Random downvotes like these without justification? What might be the reason for such downvote.

Thanks

Comment: This question got a downvote without any note on how I can improve too

Comment: While I'm not a downvoter on either this or your Answer on main, I can point out that there have been numerous discussions of "why I got downvotes" previously.  It is important to do a reasonable job of research before asking (in either place).  In particular it would have become apparent that voting, whether up or down, on the quality of posts is anonymous and therefore typically done "without justification".

Comment: "I see that lot of queries like these arise at Meta" – and did they not raise exactly the question you are raising here? and did you expect to learn anything new by raising the question again?

Comment: I have added the tag ([meta-tag:specific-answer]) as your question seem to be mainly about this one particular instance (see [the tag info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-answer/info)). Regarding your general question about downvotes without a comment, this has been discussed on meta several times. For example: [Can a down/up votes be accompanied by a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1479), [Downvoting for no stated reason is abusive](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3153), [In praise of silence](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9404), ...

Comment: ... [Why is it that people down vote an answer without even bothering to comment what is the problem?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18891), [Can we be nicer to downvoters?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23486), etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are likely two non-related issues:

- The answer you gave uses a development of $\tan(x)$, at least initially without much comment, which is in a way stronger than what is asked in the question. Thus, the reasoning feels a bit circular. This is a general problem with these types of *questions* (not the answers), it is  often not made clear what is used as the definition of the trigonometric function, what is known, etc. This can change drastically what is a reasonable answer.
- You answered an old and answered question. If you do not add something quite substantive over the existing answers this is often not received well.

On the general inquiry it is acceptable to downvote without comment, although explanatory comments are encouraged.